# C++11 creating new threads in a detached thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I am thinking about the possibility of creating a `std::thread`, `detach()` it from the main thread while the detached thread creates threads and waits for a `join()` before running the next thread.

But I dont this as being possible as I am always crashing after the first thread but before the next.

Someplace in code:

```
std::thread t1(&B::start, this); //Launch a thread
t1.detach();
```

inside `B::start`:

```
std::thread t2(&C::start, this); //Launch a thread
t2.join();

std::thread t3(&D::start, this); //Launch a thread
t3.join();

std::thread t4(&D::start, this); //Launch a thread
t4.join();
```

inside `C::start`:

```
std::cout << "Thread t2 is starting" << std::endl;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::this_thread::sleep_until(start + std::chrono::seconds(60));
std::cout << "Thread t2 waited for 60 seconds" << std::endl;
```

inside `D::start`:

```
std::cout << "Thread t3 is starting" << std::endl;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::this_thread::sleep_until(start + std::chrono::seconds(60));
std::cout << "Thread t3 waited for 60 seconds" << std::endl;
```

inside `E::start`:

```
std::cout << "Thread t4 is starting" << std::endl;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::this_thread::sleep_until(start + std::chrono::seconds(60));
std::cout << "Thread t4 waited for 60 seconds" << std::endl;
```

So here is what I would be expecting to happen:

a thread, `t1` would be created and detached from the main thread so the main app keeps running
in `t1`, `t2` is created and sleeps for 60 seconds.
after the 60 seconds, `t3` is created and sleeps for 60 seconds.
after the 60 seconds, `t4` is created and sleeps for 60 seconds.

All while my main thread keeps running doing its thing.

UPDATE: How does one take this `std::thread t1(&B::start, this); //Launch a thread` and break it up so that I declare `std::thread t1;` in a header but do the `(&B::start, this);` where I need to and then `detach();`

Comment: What's happening after std::thread `t1.detach();` in your main thread?  If the object that it's in is destroyed, all of the others are likely to crash, since it's the same object in all of them.

Comment: `t1` is created in the constructor of an object that is stuffed into a vector for future acting upon. Can you see my update?

Comment: Acting upon *what* ? You detached it.

Comment: There is a typo in your fourth thread creation, I suspect.

Comment: @Whoz, no I stuff an object that contains some data as into a vector, not the thread

Comment: @Jason: Could you provide an sscce?

Comment: What happens to "this" after t1.detach, which is passed as an argument to t1? Does it exist for the lifetime of t1?

Comment: @Jason Comment on UPDATE: You can move a thread like this: `std::thread th; th = std::move(std::thread(&B::start, this));`

Answer (score -1):

Why do you detach your first thread? It will be running separate from your main thread anyway!

Comment: ...to be more precise: after `std::thread t1(&B::start, this);`, the thread is running! If you want to `join`with it later, you should not `detach`it.